# Scala filtering on 2 conditions to remove strings from a list

Tags: scala

This feels like it should be very simple but after several variations I'm unable to return the correct result.

I have a list of strings that I'm trying to filter on and a Set of strings that I'm using as a blacklist.  If any of the strings in my list are in the black list then I want to ignore them and only return the ones that are not present.  In addition to this I have another case that I need to check for so I need to make sure its not in the black list and also not condition two.

```
val strings = List("something", "something.else", "something-else" )
val blacklist = Set(".else", ".new", ".old")
```

I’m trying to do something like:

```
strings.filter(f => !f.endsWith("-else"))
```

to leave just "something" and "something.else" but I can’t seem to return "something" by itself.

Comment: You want the word to not be in the blacklist or just its end?

Comment: @Esardes, it's the filename extension so jsut the end

Comment: `strings.filterNot(s => blacklist.exists(s.endWith))`?

Answer (score 2):

```
strings.filter(
  f => !f.endsWith("-else") && !blacklist.exists(suffix => f.endsWith(suffix))
)
```

Or a shorter (but identical) version:

```
strings.filter(f => !f.endsWith("-else") && !blacklist.exists(f.endsWith))
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand you want to remove an element if it ends with something that is in your blacklist.
You could try something like

```
strings.filter {x => (blacklist map {word => !(x endsWith word)}  reduce( (a,b) => a && b ) ) }
```

with another condition, for example `x.length >= 2`

```
strings.filter {x => (blacklist map {word => !(x endsWith word)}  reduce( (a,b) => a && b ) ) && x.length >= 2}
```

Comment: it checks that we only have the value "true" in the set we build right before. The shorter version is to use the convenience method "exists" that Tzach Zohar uses in his answer - and that I had forgotten - , but this way you get to see the tool behind.

Comment: thank you - your time and help are much appreciated - my attempts didn't reuse 'endswith', after seeing the solutions I think it's probably more efficient if I add "-else" to the blacklist and just check the one condition